# How to manage orders according to their status?

Tags: e-commerce

How can I manage product according to their status return by shipping panel and update their status into DB please give me some ideas about on it

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem like what e-commerce platform your question is related to.

Comment: I have created a custom e-commerce site in PHP where customer came and buy products track their order status etc.

Comment: Question should be updated with appropriate problem statement along with some code or screen shots which helps the user to understand well. Otherwise, we can't provide solution. Kindly read this article to ask good questions : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask